# How to not to export Private functions in the object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to figure out how to not to exports the private functions when using functions in the objects.

For example, in modules.js I have the following:

```
const modelType1 = require('./Message/type1');

module.exports = {
    Type1: modelType1
}
```

`type1.js` look like this:

```
const Message = {
    publicFunction: function() {
        return 'hello!';
    },

    privateFunction: function() {
        return 'hello!';
    }
}

module.exports = Message;
```

How to not to export `privateFunction`?

When I tried to different approach without using an object which I have got it to work, for example:

```
const modelType2 = require('./Message/type2');

module.exports = {
    Type2: modelType2
}
```

`type2.js` look like this:

```
function publicFunction() {
    return "Hello"
}

function privateFunction() {
    return "Hello"
}

module.exports = {
    publicFunction
}
```

Which is best practice to use `type1.js` or `type2.js` and what the difference between them two?

Comment: Remove `privateFunction()` from the `Message` class. Place it outside the class definition. You have access to it inside the module, but not as an exported function.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Which is best practice to use `type1.js` or `type2.js` and what the difference between them two?

Comment: _Which is best practice to use_ - Personal preference. Differences: none.